# What is the use of col-*-offset-0 in bootstrap?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I know that adding an offset greater than 0 is visible when using it on a div tag. But what is the purpose of `offset-0` if it doesn't add anything tangible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> But what is the purpose of `offset-0`?

One word: **Overriding**.

You can use that class to override previous offsets. The actual rule for this class is quite simple:

```
margin-left: 0;
```

If you have a look at the official [**Bootstrap documentation**](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-offsetting) it says:

> You can also override offsets from lower grid tiers with
> `.col-*-offset-0` classes.
>
> ```
> <div class="row">
>   <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4">
>   </div>
>   <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4">
>   </div>
>   <div class="col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-3 col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-0">
>   </div>
> </div>
> ```

---

#### Demo

In this demo, the blue `<div>` has the following extra classes:

- `col-xs-offset-3` which means that devices of size `xs` **and above** will get an offset equal to 3. In css this means `margin-left: 25%`.
- `col-xs-offset-0` which means that devices of size `sm` **and above** will get an offset equal to 0. In css this means `margin-left: 0`.

So if you want an offset **only for `xs` devices** you need to override this with the offset 0 for anything `sm` and above.

```css
.row div div {
  background: red;
  height: 50px;
}
.row div:last-of-type div {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4">
    <div></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4">
    <div></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-3 col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-0">
    <div></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

<sub>***Snippet best viewed in "Full page" mode and then resize viewport to see changes.***</sub>

Comment: Can you please share an example showing difference of using and not using it?